# SCCM 2007 and FEP 2012 - populate DW

Tags: sccm-2007

We had someone delete the Full FEP Collection last week. We restored the SCCM database from that morning to get the entire FEP collection back. We did not restore the FEP DB or DW, which now we really should have. My issue now is when I run a FEP report all the system show the Protection Status as Not Installed, Not protected, No Real time, and Defs are out of date. I have to assume that when the FEP collection was deleted that all this data was removed also from the FEP DW or DB.

Any new Servers that were added since the database restore are showing the correct data. I thought I take a chance to see if anyone knows the best way to get SCCM FEP to repopulate the data?